# Different vim colors and styles in Tmux and Gnome

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, colors, gnome-terminal

I am using `tmux`, and recently found out that the same vim colorshemes inside and outside of tmux have different colors

Left is `tmux` in `gnome-terminal`, right is plain `gnome-terminal`, `gnome-terminal` has default colors:

[image: ![Left is <code>tmux</code> in <code>gnome-terminal</code>, right is plain <code>gnome-terminal</code>]

EDIT: At closer look, the style does change too (look at bold etc).

Both terminals are 256-colored ones (`gnome-terminal` indicates himself as `xterm-256color`, `tmux` as `tmux-256color`, see [`ncurses-term`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ncurses-term) package), `vim` sees that too (`:set t_Co` gives 256).
I compared their color representations via

```
for i in `seq 0 255` ; do echo -e "$i: \e[48;5;${i}m                  \e[0m"; done
```

And got the same palettes:

[image: Color paletes]

I think `tmux` should just pass these colors to `gnome-terminal`, but when why `vim` changes?

Can I fix this? I think `gnome-terminal` ones are better, and want `tmux` to use them.

Comment: Which color scheme is that? Please post a copy -- it might be using rgb colors, not just 256.

Comment: Actually, Vim was loading `desert` colorsheme instead of `default`, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, it was just a Vim issue: when started in `tmux`, it loaded `default` colorsheme, but when started from plain terminal, it loaded `desert` colorscheme but still calling it `default` when asked via `:colorsheme`. Forcing `:colorsheme default` resolved an issue, so I added `colorsheme` line in my `~/.vimrc` and now it's OK.

I have no idea why Vim was doing that stuff, but forcing desired colorsheme works fine.

Comment: "I have no idea why Vim was doing that stuff": See this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349040/124274).