# Why do Vim colors look different inside and outside of tmux?

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, colors

Environment:

- Fedora 25 (4.9.12-200.fc25.x86_64)
- GNOME Terminal 3.22.1 Using VTE version 0.46.1 +GNUTLS
- VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2017 16:26:11)
- tmux 2.2

I recently started using tmux and have observed that the colors within Vim change depending on whether I'm running inside or outside of tmux.  Below are screenshots of Vim outside (left) and inside (right) of tmux while viewing a Git diff:

[image]

My `TERM` variable is

- Outside tmux: `xterm-256color`
- Inside tmux: `screen-256color`

Vim reports these terminal types as expected (via `:set term?`):

- Outside tmux: `term=xterm-256color`
- Inside tmux: `term=screen-256color`

Vim also reports both instances are running in 256-color mode (via `:set t_Co?`):

- Outside tmux: `t_Co=256`
- Inside tmux: `t_Co=256`

There are many similar questions out there regarding getting Vim to run in 256-color mode inside tmux (the best answer I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15378816/3900879)), but I don't think that's my problem given the above information.

I can duplicate the problem outside of tmux if I run Vim with the terminal type set to `screen-256color`:

```
$ TERM=screen-256color vim
```

So that makes me believe there's simply some difference between the `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color` terminal capabilities that causes the difference in color.  Which leads to the question posed in the title: **what specifically in the terminal capabilities causes the Vim colors to be different?**  I see the differences between running `:set termcap` inside and outside of tmux, but I'm curious as to which variables actually cause the difference in behavior.

Independent of the previous question, **is it possible to have the Vim colors be consistent when running inside or outside of tmux?**  Some things I've tried include:

- Explicitly setting the default terminal tmux uses in `~/.tmux.conf` to various values (some against the advice of the tmux [FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/FAQ#L8)):

```
    set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
    set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
    set -g default-terminal "screen.xterm-256color"
    set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

- Starting tmux using `tmux -2`.

In all cases, Vim continued to display different colors inside of tmux.

Comment: Could you please start `script`, start `vim`, quit `vim` and then quit `script`'s shell, and attach the resulting `typescript` file? Then repeat the same steps with `TERM=screen-256color vim` instead.

Comment: @egmont Here you go: [typescript-xterm-256color](http://pastebin.com/xT5PHM3t) and [typescript-screen-256color](http://pastebin.com/7JSbw82n).

Comment: I can see 256-color escape sequences in the `xterm-256color` version (search for "38;5;" in the file), but cannot in the `screen-256color`. E.g. wherever there's a `\e[38;5;81m` in `xterm-256color` (color #81 of the 256-color palette, a middle blue shade), `screen-256color` contains `\e[34m` instead (the standard blue of the 8-color palette). So the main question is why does vim not use the 256-color palette in case of `TERM=screen-256color`.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that the `xterm-256color` version seems to print the screen twice, first with the legacy colors and then with the 256-color palette. Search for e.g. "F1" in the file, you'll find two matches in `xterm-256color`, the first with `\e[34m` color, the second with `\e[38;5;81m`. I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Adding `set -g default-terminal "screen.xterm-256color"` in `~/.tmux.conf` and reload the config in tmux (<C-s>: source-file ~/.tmux.conf) worked for me (highlight issue). thx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`tmux` doesn't support the terminfo capability **`bce`** (back color erase), which `vim` checks for, to decide whether to use its "default color" scheme.

That characteristic of `tmux` has been mentioned a few times -

- [Reset background to transparent with tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57700/reset-background-to-transparent-with-tmux/321576#321576)
- [Clear to end of line uses the wrong background color in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251847/clear-to-end-of-line-uses-the-wrong-background-color-in-tmux/252078#252078)

Answer (score 54):

I had the similar issue before. Comments in blue in Vim were hard to read. In `.tmux.conf` I set this:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

And in `.vimrc`:

```
set background=dark
```

Now it looks as follows and works both in Gnome Terminal and Cygwin:
[image]

Comment: This solved it for me. For some reason, inside tmux, vim wasn't detecting a dark background. Explicitly setting `bg=dark` in my vimrc fixed it.

Comment: Strange - my `$TERM` both inside and outside `tmux` was `"xterm-256color"` and explicitly setting the backgroun did it for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too. I thought the problem was with `stterm` because in `xfce4-terminal` everything looked comfortable(comments appearing in `cyan` instead of `blue` which is very hard to read with dark background).  after this change everything works fine. But remember to add `unlet! skip_defaults_vim
        source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` to vimrc file to use syntax highlighting etc...

Answer (score 15):

The following settings inside `~/.tmux.conf` worked for me:

```
# file ~/.tmux.conf
# ...

set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"

# make colors inside tmux look the same as outside of tmux
# see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/696
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786092
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"

# ...
```

Comment: Ummmm you sir, have the only answer that works! Every other answer does not work in my case, Thank you, 1000x upvote if I could.

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Comment: This answer worked for me (windows terminal + tmux + https://github.com/cideM/yui colorscheme)

Comment: Many thanks! This fixed my NeoVim colorscheme with tmux + foot terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @egmont's analysis of what colors Vim was outputting when `TERM=screen-256color`, I was inspired to look at the color scheme Vim is using in the two scenarios.

Vim reports it is using the `default` color scheme in **both** cases.  I thought that odd because the `default` color scheme on Fedora 25 (`/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/default.vim`) doesn't appear to match the colors I actually see when `TERM=xterm-256color`.  If I explicitly set the color scheme using `:colorscheme default` when `TERM=xterm-256color`, Vim's appearance changes to that when `TERM=screen-256color`.  To get the colors back to what they were when I first start Vim, I had to use the `ron` color scheme.  Progress!

I found an Ask Ubuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24548) that suggests that when Vim reports it is using the `default` color scheme, it doesn't necessarily mean `default.vim` but rather some theme-specific color scheme.  As the answer points out, a dark theme (which I am using) corresponds to the `ron` color scheme, just as I discovered above.  (Even though this post is with respect to Ubuntu, I'm assuming the OP was using GNOME.)

I also found another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278954/different-vim-colors-and-styles-in-tmux-and-gnome) that seems to describe the same problem I'm having.  I came across it while searching before I posted this question, but, for some reason, the color scheme didn't strike me as being relevant.

I ended up doing what @LapshinDmitry did in his answer and explicitly set `colorscheme ron` in my `~/.vimrc` file.  Now, whether I start Vim inside or outside of tmux, the colors appear the same.  The only drawback is if I ever change my desktop theme from a dark flavor to a light flavor, Vim won't automatically switch to the "default" light theme color scheme, which is apparently `peachpuff`.  I can live with that, as I'm unlikely to ever change my theme.

I'm not going to accept this answer because I consider explicitly setting the color scheme in my `~/.vimrc` a workaround rather than the solution.  If someone can explain why Vim loads a different "default" color scheme depending on the value of `TERM`, I'll be happy to accept that answer, as I'm more interested in understanding the root cause.  I suspect it has something to do with how Vim interprets the terminal capabilities between the two terminfo files.

Comment: I'm also curious why `vim` behaves this way. After all, the `bce` capability should have nothing to do with the available number of colors.

Comment: @egmont I interpreted @ThomasDickey's answer as: 1) Vim checks the `bce` capability of the terminal, 2) if present, select color scheme "A", 3) otherwise, select color scheme "B".  I believe the color _depth_ is the same in both cases (i.e. 256 colors, as `t_Co` shows).  It's just that color scheme "B" on my system happens to only use an 8-color palette even though 256 colors are _possible_ (I _think_ that explains what you observed in your typescript analysis; please correct me if I'm wrong).  Remember, after I run `:colorscheme ron`, I see 256-color escape sequences in the same Vim session.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I still cannot see any rationale behind this though. Nevermind. `vim` has really weird design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

For me I have to add below into the `.tmux.conf` to get the RGB color and *eliminate* the color difference.

```
set -ag terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:RGB"
set  -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

Answer (score 0):

> My TERM variable is
>      Outside tmux: xterm-256color
>      Inside tmux: screen-256color

That's correct and working for me. Try it with a different terminal (I use urxvt) to see if Gnome Terminal is the problem.
﻿

Also check `COLORTERM` (mine is set to `rxvt`) and `unset TERMCAP`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I ran the same test with urxvt (outer `TERM`  is `rxvt-unicode-256color`) using an appropriate `~/.Xdefaults` and unfortunately still observed different colors inside and outside of tmux.  For the gnome-terminal scenario, `COLORTERM` is `truecolor` and `TERMCAP` is empty both inside and outside tmux.  For the urxvt scenario, `COLORTERM` is `rxvt-xpm` outside and `truecolor` inside tmux, while `TERMCAP` is empty both inside and outside tmux.

Comment: @RustyShackleford this is only for Vim? Are you using 'termguicolors'? Take a look at `:help xterm-true-color` or try with a more default Vim config.

Comment: I've only noticed the problem in Vim so far (like I said, I only recently started using tmux).  For example, my terminal prompt and Git CLI output appear to have the same colors both inside and outside of tmux.  I do not set `termguicolors` in my `.vimrc` and `:set termguicolors?` reports `notermguicolors` in both cases.  I'll look at the help topic you referenced; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I have some new findings.

1. In VIM, there are default color schemes and a color scheme named 'default'. Confusing, huh? The default color schemes are 'ron' for dark background, and 'default' otherwise. Checking
   https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/colors/default.vim, `set bg&` is causing the trouble.
2. Only dark background is affected by this problem because the background is mistaken as light. Query `:set background?` to find out.
3. iTerm2 works with no issue when `TERM=screen-256color`. But it still does not work when you run tmux in iTerm2. The reason is iTerm use COLORFGBG, which vim can use to determine bg. This explains many magic behaviours. iTerm2 sometimes adds COLORFGBG, but sometimes not.

workaround:

1. Explicitly set colorscheme, e.g. `colorscheme ron`
2. `set background=dark`
3. Passing query of bg to outer terminal by

```
if exists("$TMUX")
    let &t_RB = "\ePtmux;\e\e]11;?\007\e\\"
endif
```

So far, this is the method I'm using. The best would be tmux to implement support of osc 11 sequences and Vim recognize tmux and set t_RB accordingly.